# Apache Kafka is starting to slow down

Tags: apache-kafka

Once the data offset in a topic goes over ~35000 (always different), it starts to take 10+ seconds to transfer messages between the producer and the consumer in a particular topic. Up to this threshold, messages are transmitted instantly. How to solve this problem? I guess I need to correct the topik configuration?

Deleting a topic and creating a new one solves the problem, but I wish I didn't have to do that.

P.s: The problem was solved by setting retention.ms and segment.ms to lower values. The problem was the number of messages in the topic.

Comment: Need more details, please. Kafka isn't tuned for performance with any of the default settings. Have you modified the open file handle limit of the Kafka broker? What types of disks format is used by the broker? How much heap space is available?

Comment: Can you provide more details: how many brokers? how many partitions this topic has? what is the average size of the messages (bytes)?